# Rails/Mongoid best way to save sortable ordered list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, mongoid, jquery-ui-sortable

I've got a sortable list of players pulled from my db. Users can rank them in order of their preference.

What's the best way to store that order in the db associated with each player's preference and retrieve player stats back in that same order?

Right now I'm retrieving by `@playersdraftlist = @draftlist.map { |id| Player.find(id) }`, but this hits the db many times.

So, currently, I have a User model and a Draft model. The draft only has an associated `user_id`.

1) Would it be better to just store the draftees as a user field instead of a separate model?

2) Is there a better way to store a list like this when I need to retain dupes and order?

Structure:

`PlayerDraft` model has an associated `user_id`:

```
  draftees: [
    "52f4fd9f52e39bc0c15674ea", #Peyton
    "52f4fd9f52e39bc0c15674eb", #Tom
    "52f4fd9f52e39bc0c15674ea"  #Peyton
  ],
  user_id: "52f581096b657612fe020000"
```

`@draftees = Draft.find(user_id = current_user._id).first.draftees` will return the draftees array.

Calling `Player.find(@draftees)` will remove the duplicates and order by _id.

**Edit**

Here is my poor solution:

```
  def index
    @players = Player.all

    if current_user.draft_list.draftees == [""]
      @playersdraftlist = ""

    else
      # Get all picks for current user
      @picks = current_user.draft_list.draftees
      @draft = Player.find(@picks)
      @playersdraftlist = @picks.map { |id| Player.find(id) }

    end
  end
```

Comment: See my update. Does this explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this is to use the identity map in mongoid.
There are more details on this here: http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/identity_map.html

But the short and simple way to do this is in your `mongoid.yml` set the following property:
`identity_map_enabled: true`

Then search for the following: `Player.find(@draftees)`
And this will return your draftees in the order of the array that you passed in. One caveat is that it won't return duplicates so your `@draftees` array above if used would return only two values (the order is based on the first appearance of the id, so it will return the player with id "52f4fd9f52e39bc0c15674ea" first and then the player with id "52f4fd9f52e39bc0c15674eb"). So you will have to recreate the duplicates via some sort of abstraction.

Here is one possible way to do this, and it was inspired by a comment posted by @muistooshort below:

In your `User` class add the following function

```
def get_draftee_list
  players = Player.find(self.draftees).each_with_object({}) { |p, h| h[p.id] = p } 
  return self.draftees.map { |id| players[Moped::BSON::ObjectId.from_string(id)] }
end
```

Note: This was tested on Mongoid 3

This should solve your problem since each call to `raw_data.find(id)` is searching the result set from your the initial query which is stored in memory and not making another query to the db

Comment: Good info. Your answer is correct, but to be fully counted, I need to know how to include duplicates. As of now, I'm better off staying with the hash map.

Comment: Ok, I've updated the answer with how I would do it so that you don't make consecutive DB calls. I expect an upvote now :P

Comment: Sounds good. I'll update my proj and clarify if I need to. Thank you. This should be less expensive than my current method, correct?

Comment: I think it will, but you should check your logs to see how long your previous method took versus how long this method takes just to confirm. I recommend you add the new relic gem to your app and see how many DB queries each way makes and how long it takes to return each query

Comment: You could also `players = Player.find(self.draftees).each_with_object({}) { |p, h| h[p.id] = p }` and then `self.draftees.map { |id| players[id] }`.

Comment: Good advice. I'm kind a noob for CS and RoR. :) For something simple like this, would it be okay to tie up in another model, since I've really created an entire model for one field??

Comment: @muistooshort, can you elaborate?

Comment: Rather than going through `find` over and over again (which has to do a bunch of work to parse the arguments, go through the identity map, ...), just cache the players in an id->obj Hash using one `find` call and then use the `draftees.map` to convert the IDs in `draftees` (which are in the correct order and may have duplicates) to Player objects.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong...I'm getting `[null, null, null, null]` back.

Comment: @alalani, I've clarified my question a little. Perhaps that will help? Sorry to be so vague to begin with.

Comment: @KevinBrown, sorry I just realized that my answer won't work for you because it uses an internal library we developed here at work. I tried  the code posted by @muistooshort and got all nulls. The reason is that the keys for the players hash aren't strings but rather BSON Object Ids. Try this: `players = Player.find(self.draftees).each_with_object({}) { |p, h| h[p.id] = p }` and then `self.draftees.map { |id| players[Moped::BSON::ObjectId.from_string(id)] }`. Note: this approach assumes that you are using the default mongoid ids for all your models

Comment: @alalani, do I need the Moped gem?? (stupid question?) I'm using mongoid as mapper...conflicts? Am I confused about the difference between mongoid/moped?

Comment: @KevinBrown it should be installed automatically as a dependency by the mongoid gem. To confirm, check you Gemfile.lock and search for moped

Comment: @alalani, sounds good. I'll check this when I'm off from work. I'll also edit with the solution I created and you let me know which is better?

Comment: @alalani, I'm getting closer...gotta fiddle a bit. NOTE: For mongoid-4, `Moped::BSON` is just `BSON`. :)

Comment: @KevinBrown, oh cool. I'm running Mongoid 3 so you might have to make some changes. What part isn't working for you?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47889/discussion-between-alalani-and-kevin-brown)